# Property 'maxPointers' does not exist on type 'HammerInput'

Tags: angular, visual-studio, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, hammer.js

Execution of code is not giving any error. But VSCode is giving this error. Saying property 'maxPointers' does not exist on type 'HammerInput'. Though it exists when I see in console. But how to remove this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it says, it's a TS Lint issue. It is shown because the type of variable `eve` isn't explicit.

**Option 1**

One way to workaround it is to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) to access the `maxPointers` property

```js
mc.on('some event', (eve) => {
  if(eve['maxPointers'] === 1) {
    console.log('maxp');
  }
});
```

**Option 2**

Another workaround would be to define the variable `eve` as type `any`

```js
mc.on('some event', (eve: any) => { // <-- `any` type
  if(eve.maxPointers === 1) {
    console.log('maxp');
  }
});
```